# React-native : Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavawithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am relatively new to react-native and gradle (coding in general). I am trying to run my code on my phone but I keep getting the following error: `Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavawithJavac'`.

I have tried looking for a solution but none of it worked. I have tried:

1. **reinstalling the environmental variable JAVA_HOME**,
2. **ran gradlew clean**, and
3. also did **npm install** in my android folder but nothing worked.

Here is the response I've gotten:

```
C:\Users\Saint\OneDrive\Desktop\Important Stuff\Programming stuff\react\Calendar\android\app\src\main\java\com\Calendar\MainApplication.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
                         ^

  symbol:   class ReactApplication 
  location: package com.facebook.react 
C:\Users\Saint\OneDrive\Desktop\Important Stuff\Programming stuff\react\Calendar\android\app\src\main\java\com\Calendar\MainApplication.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
                         ^

  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: package com.facebook.react
C:\Users\Saint\OneDrive\Desktop\Important Stuff\Programming stuff\react\Calendar\android\app\src\main\java\com\Calendar\MainApplication.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
                                                            ^

  symbol: class ReactApplication
C:\Users\Saint\OneDrive\Desktop\Important Stuff\Programming stuff\react\Calendar\android\app\src\main\java\com\Calendar\MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
                ^

  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
C:\Users\Saint\OneDrive\Desktop\Important Stuff\Programming stuff\react\Calendar\android\app\src\main\java\com\Calendar\MainApplication.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() 
         ^

  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
C:\Users\Saint\OneDrive\Desktop\Important Stuff\Programming stuff\react\Calendar\android\app\src\main\java\com\Calendar\MainActivity.java:5: error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPackages() in ReactActivity
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
       ^

C:\Users\Saint\OneDrive\Desktop\Important Stuff\Programming stuff\react\Calendar\android\app\src\main\java\com\Calendar\MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
                                                       ^

  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
C:\Users\Saint\OneDrive\Desktop\Important Stuff\Programming stuff\react\Calendar\android\app\src\main\java\com\Calendar\MainApplication.java:35: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^

8 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
13 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 12 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: Here is my build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be several compilation errors that you need to fix to get going. What does your build.gradle dependency look like, Do you have all the dependencies that are needed? Feel free to share relevant code snippet that might help

Comment: hey Roshan, I've just updated the post and here's my dependencies. I dont think I have added any dependencies, and i dint really know I had to add them... Ill try to get that fix and get back to you. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I have deleted the entire folder and ran npm install and it somehow worked! thanks for the help either ways!

Comment: Always good to hear that :)